# Xdebug makes PHP way too slow

Tags: php, apache, docker, xdebug

I know that Xdebug makes PHP slower, but on my Ubuntu 16 PC it makes PHP much slower only when listening to Xdebug is enabled in PhpStorm, in other cases speed is fine.

But now I'm trying to install development environment on MacOS with Docker.

So in few words: I've found a benchmark script. When I check PHP speed with Xdebug installed and enabled, it takes about 28-32 seconds to execute it. If I build a container without Xdebug installed and configured, script execution time is about 0.8-1.1 sec which is 30+ times faster!

Is there a chance that I configured something wrong and server sends 'Xdebug response' all the time?

Not sure actually how that works, but I am sure that it should not be like that.

I am using Docker, Ubuntu 16.04 container, PHP 7.2, Xdebug v2.9.1, Apache.

Here are my Xdebug settings:

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=PHP_STORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

Yet another thing. I am able to start debugging with this [Xdebug listening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpm1.png)
icon, when all guides say that I should use 'Add Configuration' option and add Xdebug service.

Could you please tell me if I am doing something wrong?

[image: Xdebug listening]

Comment: At least you could do, is to run the latest version: 2.9.2. In your case, you have two problems: Docker makes things extra slower, macOS makes things extra slower. In any case, when you're debugging, the debugger does work, so I would be slower. However, the difference shouldn't be that big unless you're using a really inefficient framework or something.

Comment: @Derick I am actually using a huge CMS but i really feel enormous difference between debugger being installed and not installed. I am fine about the speed of docker on MacOS but debugger makes it impossible to work. I am fine if it was of that speed when i am listening to debugger (as it works on my Ubuntu PC) but it has the same speed all the time.

Comment: @ДимаЛизунов When Xdebug connects to PhpStorm, IDE will configure certain settings, sets breakpoints and then just let it execute -- no communication should be happening here until the very end when Xdebug tells "I'm done / session is over", unless you have conditional breakpoints that IDE must evaluate every time that line gets executed. Enable Xdebug log and check what it has to say about it -- it will show if IDE tries to set any breakpoints etc.

Comment: @ДимаЛизунов Regarding "Debug listening icon vs Run/Debug Configuration" -- there is no difference here. When you create configuration and hit "Debug" it start listening and pass needed params to the URL/CLI executable to start debug session. When you just use "phone handle icon", it always listens on Xdebug port for incoming connections but you control the actual "debug me" cookie/URL param or another "debug this request" flag.

Comment: @ДимаЛизунов Not going to comment on Docker and Mac. I'm on Windows, usually running on local IIS for most sites (nts PHP builds, x64), sometimes using proper VM under VMware. For local native execution, the difference with Xdebug enabled (in php.ini; no debug attempts) is about 2 .. 2.3 times slower than if xdebug extension is disabled/commented out (that's about 1.5 year old tests that I did; using PHP 7.2 IIRC). I can only suggest to check Xdebug log and see what does it do when it tries to debug (establishes or tries to establish debug session).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your comments. I'll check that a little bit later. but as you mentioned, enabling xdebug should make code being executed like 2 times slower, but not 30 times.
I'll try to check logs.

Comment: In the latest version of Windows, PHP 7.2 and Docker and Xdebug, I have exactly these same issue. It's terribly slow making it impossible to debug. It takes more than one minutes to start the actual debugging. One you can trace the first line, it can be continued normally.

Comment: is docker slowing everything ..even you will not accept that

Comment: just guessing in the dark here, two shots:
1.: is XDebug just adding too much on the overall memory footprint, so the container starts swapping? 
2.: What makes me wonder is: you have Xdebug enabled without autostart but you say it's always running? how did you initiate the session? could it be, that profiling (the config shows it's disabled but just to be sure?) or tracing mode is running as well?

Happy to see @Derick is active here as well and jumping in first as the creator of Xdebug <3

Comment: @LazyOne have you figure this out? I'm on a Mac, PHP 7.4 and XDebug 3 and have this exact issue. Page load times going 30+ seconds when active, less than 2 inactive. I'm just running the most basic debug setup - not even using any of the remote profiling.

Comment: @badcrocodile Disable Xdebug runtime (for v3 -- `xdebug.mode=off`) -- any better? I mean: how fast compared to having it disabled completely (not loaded) and in normal debug mode. How much slower it will be in `xdebug.mode=develop` mode? In any case: in my projects it's quite fast (I mean: no HUGE delays like some of the guys are seeing here)

Comment: @badcrocodile What I've noticed though .. that when debugging in PhpStorm .. it may be slow for few reasons: 1) having too many breakpoints; 2) You have A LOT of global constants/global variables defined; 3) have a lot of local variables (huge arrays, big objects, lots of watches in PhpStorm) -- all those need to be refreshed after each step.

Comment: @badcrocodile 4) Some Xdebug settings will generate much more context/debug info (defaults are fine, it's when user adjusts them to be more verbose/detailed -- go through and check them: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings). Also check https://php.watch/articles/xdebug2-vs-3-benchmark

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the somewhat same issue, there was a problem with my configuration.

I was connecting to web server via a remote network address (like 192.168.xx.xx, 10.10.xx.xx) instead of local machine address (like 127.0.0.1 or localhost).

May be there was some routing issues within my docker configuration or some other settings. Though I did not got to the root cause but it solved my problem.

This worked out and my debugging become fast.

Comment: It's not the case for me. I use local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until I found out, that the Xdebug extension in Chrome was causing this. If it is disabled the loading times are fine, if it is enabled a page reload often times took over 60s compared to 5s with Xdebug disabled. Did not make any difference if Xdebug in PHPStorm or Container was enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the `discover_client_host` option, when enabled the requests are very slow, I set it to `xdebug.discover_client_host = false` and the requests became much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I used docker-compose to switch between two php instances (one with xdebug and the other without it)

The apache containers switches based on the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie value (`PHPSTORM` by default)

Here's the interesting part of the configuration

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /XDEBUG_SESSION=${XDEBUG_COOKIE_VALUE}/">
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php_xdebug:9000"
</If>
<Else>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
</Else>
```

Docker compose script
https://github.com/unlocomqx/conditional-xdebug-fpm-docker